# Laravel: How to make relationship accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I have relations in model `UserTasks` to `Review` model

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class,'task_id');
}
```

I'm loading reviews using `with`

```
UserTasks::with('reviews');
```

And I want to format `reviews` relation output using **accessors** in `UserTasks` model

```
public function getReviewsAttribute($reviews)
{
    // FILTER AND FORMAT RELATION OUTPUT
    foreach ($reviews as &$review) {
        if ($review['active'] == true) {
            $review['cid'] = bcrypt($this->cid);
            $reviews = [$review];
        }
    }
    return $reviews;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work

Relationships loaded using `with` do not pay attention to accessor

I read that it is almost impossible, but maybe someone know the way to format loaded relations using accessors

Comment: Why not put the accessors in Reviews?

Comment: please mention more details about question.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I do not understand what more details need to be indicated

Comment: you are trying this public function getReviewsAttribute($rewiews)
{
    foreach ($rewiews as &$rewiew) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH REVIEWS
    }
    return $rewiews; 
} but where is $reviews?

Comment: @aynber I want to filter `reviews` relation output without modifying `Reviews` model

Comment: @ChiragPatel when I load relation `reviews` using `with(['reviews'])` I have `reviews` attribute in UserTasks model
So I want to have accessor for this `reviews` attribute

Comment: You cannot do that. You can however use appends property on model and a relationship to do what you want. Check the manual for details

Comment: is UserTasks a model that uses a pivot table? Please say no

Comment: @Indra no, UserTasks doesn`t use pivot table

Comment: @Indra I know that Laravel can't do that, but I thought there are some hacks)

Comment: yeah. it can't unfortunately. I usually make a function in the model to deal with this type of situation

Comment: @Indra I already done function to format `UserTasks` collection before output. But, I think using accessors for relations would be a very useful trick

Answer (score 2):

If you want all reviews in **UserTasks** model than you can try this

```
public function getReviewsAttribute($reviews)
{
    $reviews = $this->reviews;
    foreach ($reviews as $rewiew) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH REVIEWS
    }
    return $reviews; 
}
```

By `$reviews = Review::all();` this you will get all reviews and you can do whatever you want to do.

> Don't forget to add namespace at top of your model like  use Review;(give your namespace)

Comment: You should use appends property and the relations in model. Doing it with for like that can be very bad for loading times or huge databases

Comment: @Indra I know that but questioner has not defined that from where reviews will come that is the problem.

Comment: I agree, more info is needed @Chirag Patel

Comment: @ChiragPatel I don't need to load all records from `Review` model. I need to get them from relation

Comment: So you have to use **$this->reviews** in your **UserTasks** model. I am  updating answer.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I know that I can use appends for this, but I thought that is the way to use accessors for relations :)
Unfortunately laravel can't do that.
Anyway, thank you for answers

Comment: I'd like to note $reviews->each(function($value, $index){}); it's the Laravel way since it directly works with collections. I would recommend checking out refactoring to collections. +1 Chirag Patel for solving the issue

Comment: @Indra in my code `foreach` was just a quick outline, sure,  I'll use collections methods